# The space the constant "C" occupies in bytes

Tags: c++

What I am asking is how many bytes the constant "C" occupies and why.

When I use

```
cout << sizeof("C") << endl;
```

it outputs 2.

I also wanted to ask if this is the proper method to get the answer to my question.

Thank you.

Comment: that's not a constant though.. it's  a character 
sizeof('c') will give 1 byte , inserting double quotations around it will make it a string.

Comment: It's the proper method in this case. But in general sizeof does not tell you the amount of space an object occupies. Try sizeof on a `std::string` for instance and you see the result has no relation to the number of characters in the string.

Comment: @john "But in general `sizeof` does not tell you the amount of space an object occupies." evaluating to the size of an object is the exact definition of the result of `sizeof`: "The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes occupied by a non-potentially-overlapping object of the type of its operand." That `std::string` only keeps a pointer to its data doesn't change that.

Comment: @Arey whats your point?

Comment: @Swordfish I'm not using the word object in the technical sense that you are.

Comment: @john Well, maybe you should have talked about the size of an object and all data thats related to it then. ;p

Answer (score 4):

`"C"` is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), which is really an *array* of const characters. And all string literals are *null-terminated*. That means the array needs to contain space for the terminator, which increases its size by one char.